# I have lost my sculpture in sculpting mode

Tags: modeling, scripting

[image]Help! I cant find my sculpture. I can see it in layout and modeling. But When I go to sculpting mode. I'm in a space trying navigate my way to it. With zero results. How do I find it?

Comment: Hello and welcome. What if you hit Numbpad period(.) on your keyboard?...It is kind of unclear what you are asking. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: What happens if you come out of Local view ( "/" on the numpad)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

1. Go to layout or modelling tab and find your objects.
2. Go to *Sculpting Mode* again.

Or another thing happened.
You might have used softing tools and objects shrank so much.